# Customize the directory of Karate HTML reports

Tags: karate

I am looking into organizing HTML reports into directories other than the default `target/surefire-reports`.

I have read in the docs that there is an existing `reportDir()` method for `Runner`. Can I utilize this method for JUnit 5 tests? If not, are there any other ways?

I came across a similar [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65557189/how-to-output-karate-test-results-to-custom-folders-instead-of-target) but I am not using executable jar version so the accepted answer would not be applicable.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please start trying the 1.0 RC version: https://github.com/intuit/karate/wiki/1.0-upgrade-guide - there are changes to the `Runner` API and how you can control the report output dir.

And there is no reason to make this customizable for JUnit based tests, that option is only for developer convenience: https://stackoverflow.com/a/65578167/143475

Also note that in the 1.0 version, if the reports dir already exists, it will be renamed - and maybe that behavior is sufficient.

Any other change may require you to contribute code.

Also see: https://stackoverflow.com/a/69490494/143475