# Is there a way to get the path of temp karate reporting folder

Tags: report, karate

I've recently discovered the karate framework. Great work! I've extended the standalone jar with custom java helpers to be able to access DB and ssh servers.

I transfer logs and results files from the ssh server to the server in which I run karate.
I'd like to store these files aside the HTML report. But, as long as the test runs, the report folder has a temporary name. It is renamed at then end of the run.

Is there a way to get this temporary name (or path) to be able to copy files into it?

Best regards,
Patrice from France

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a bit of a surprise for me, because as far as I know the folder is `target/karate-reports`. Maybe this is some weird thing that happens only on Windows. I'd request you to see if you can debug and contribute code to the project, that would be really great !

Since you are writing Java code and adding it to the classpath I guess, then you should probably use the `Runner` API that gives you more control, and also the option to disable Karate trying to "backup" the existing old reports folder. This is explained here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/66685944/143475

There is also an option to customize the name of the reports folder: `reportDir()`.

For this kind of control, we recommend using Karate in Java / Maven project fashion, but you can decide what works best for you.

Comment: Thank you Peter for this so quick answer. As I'm a business analyst, I'm stuck with the standalone jar. In fact I customize the target folder with the -o option to be able to manager "multi project" testing with one launcher. You're right, the karate reports subfloder is karate-reports. And there is no "temp" name. I dreamt. I think that I have a problem with relative path.

Comment: Hi, I've made some further tests. The karate-reports folder is created only at the end of the karate execution. That's why I cannot copy some more logs aside the HTML report.