Generate Multiple Karate test reports using Karate, Cucumber, and Java
How do I generate multiple Karate reports using Karate, Cucumber, and Java? The following code only generates tests from the second test2 run. What is the proper methodology?
class ApiMockRunner {

    private static List<String> jsonPaths = new ArrayList<>();

    @Test
    public void testSample() {

        Results test1Results = Runner.path("classpath:Karate/test1.feature")
                .outputCucumberJson(true)
                .karateEnv(System.getProperty("karate.env"))
                .parallel(5);

        addJsonFiles(test1Results.getReportDir());


        Results test2results = Runner.path("classpath:Karate/test2results.feature")
                .outputCucumberJson(true)
                .karateEnv(System.getProperty("karate.env"))
                .parallel(5);

        addJsonFiles(test2results.getReportDir());
    }

    public void addJsonFiles(String karateOutputPath) {
        Collection<File> jsonFiles = FileUtils.listFiles(new File(karateOutputPath), new String[] {"json"}, true);
        for (File jsonFileItem : jsonFiles) {
            jsonPaths.add(jsonFileItem.getAbsolutePath());
        }
    }

    @AfterAll
    public static void createConfig() {
        String testProjectName = "finalData";
        Configuration config = new Configuration(new File("target/"+testProjectName), testProjectName);
        ReportBuilder reportBuilder = new ReportBuilder(jsonPaths, config);
        reportBuilder.generateReports();
    }
}


Normally you run all your tests in one shot. By default Karate copies the "most recent test results" to a folder and then runs the new test, so all your reports are there.
This answer may give you some tips on how to proceed: https://stackoverflow.com/a/69490494/143475
